# How to create custom model for the facebook api

Tags: python, django, facebook-graph-api, python-2.7

Context:  Facebook graph API , Django, Python 2.7

I want to use the facebook graph api in python (that's ok) , and I'am curently learning this language.

I want to generate response automaticaly from facebook using infos of the users in the models.py , pass it one by one to the facebook API, get the infos and update database. But this need to run automaticaly.
The goal is to collect statistics (so user don't need to update each time, and don't overload the server with request it's why I want that the script run automaticaly in the backend).

Example:

The user has a page (one or more), and he want to get stat for it:
So we know the name of the page because the user add in by the forms.py of django, but I want to pass automaticaly the info so we can made graph with it (likes, follow, ...)

Here is my `models.py`:

```
 class FacebookPage(models.Model):
        user_property = models.OneToOneField(User)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name


class FacebookPageUpdate(FacebookPage):
        page_link = models.URLField()
        page_id = models.BigIntegerField()
        category = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        likes = models.BigIntegerField()
        new_like = models.IntegerField()
        talking_about_count = models.BigIntegerField()
        update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        is_community_page = models.BooleanField()
        is_published = models.BooleanField()
        checkins = models.IntegerField()
        username = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

and here is what I write in python

```
from facebi.connect import token

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
### the object_name is the name of the page from the models.PY    
datas = graph.get_object(object_name)  

#### Get Values from API page Return 

page_id = datas['id']
page_link = datas['link']
name = datas['name']
username = datas['username']
category = datas['category']
likes = datas['likes']
new_likes = datas['new_like_count']
talking_about_count = datas['talking_about_count']
is_community_page = datas['is_community_page']
is_published = datas['is_published']
checkins = datas['checkins']
```

But for now I'm stuck, and I don't know how to pass it to each other one by one and update the django database.

Thank you for your help

Julien

Comment: Do you ask how to store the values of `graph.get_object(object_name)` in the `User` model?

Comment: Not in the user model but in my custom models ( user can have multiple pages) , and I want also to run the API call each x hours automaticaly and store in the db to get the info up to date so user don't need to go to a view to update it. In this way I can provide stats for a long period.

Comment: This means: you have he Problem that you can not store a custom object in the database because there is no field type `data = models.SpecialFieldTypeForYourUsecase(...)`, right?

Comment: Right, in first time I store my python code in page.py (in the same folder than the app ) and when I made a syncdb I have this error.